# Filtragem em DataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, ado.net, filtro

Olá, estou com um problema para realizar filtros em um `DataGridView` estou utilizando Windows Forms e puxando informações de um banco de dados MySql para o `DataGridView` chamado **`dgvDados`** as informações estão sendo puxadas perfeitamente, para realizar a filtragem eu tenho um `ComboBox` chamado **`cboBusca`** e um `TextBox` chamado **`txtCriterio`** onde eu realizaria a filtragem assim Ex:

> cboBusca = "GESTOR" e txtCriterio = "João Paulo"

É um filtro bem simples para procurar uma `string` segue abaixo o código quando clicado no botão procurar

```
private void btnProcurar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         DataTable table;
         table = new DataTable();
         dgvDados.DataSource = table;

            try
            {
                table.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("" + cboBusca.Text + " like '%{0}%'", txtcriterio.Text.Replace("'", "''"));
                lblRegistros.Text = (dgvDados.Rows.Count - 1).ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "" + ex.Message, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
    }
```

Após clicar no botão `btnProcurar` para realizar a busca ele diz:

> Não é possível encontrar a coluna[GESTOR] (no caso a que eu selecionei no `cboBusca`)

Caso seja de ajuda vou deixar o código do método `CarregarGrid()` onde no caso é puxado as informações do banco

```
public void CarregarGrid()
    {
        try{
            this.dgvDados.Rows.Clear();
            //indico o número de colunas
            dgvDados.ColumnCount = 14;
            objConnection = new MySqlConnection(caminho);
            //instância do comando onde passo
            //o sql e a conexão como parâmetro
            objComando =  new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM checagens" , objConnection);
            //abro a conexão
            objConnection.Open();
            //instâncio o leitor
            var leitor = objComando.ExecuteReader();
            //enquanto leitor está lendo

        while (leitor.Read())
        {
            //insiro os dados no dgvDados
            dgvDados.Rows.Add(leitor[0].ToString(),
                leitor[1].ToString(),
                leitor[2].ToString(),
                leitor[3].ToString(),
                leitor[4].ToString(),
                leitor[5].ToString(),
                leitor[6].ToString(),
                leitor[7].ToString(),
                leitor[8].ToString(),
                leitor[9].ToString(),
                leitor[10].ToString(),
                leitor[11].ToString(),
                leitor[12].ToString(),
                leitor[13].ToString());

        }
    }
        catch(Exception ex){
            MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "" + ex.Message, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        finally{
        //fecho conexão
        objConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Eu não estou carregando as informações no `Form_Load` pois poderia ficar muito sobrecarregado então criei um botão Exibir Todos e lá eu chamo o `CarregarGrid()`

```
private void btnExibirTodos_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CarregarGrid();
        dgvDados.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
        dgvDados.Columns[0].Name = "CNPJ";
        dgvDados.Columns[1].Name = "DATA";
        dgvDados.Columns[2].Name = "RAZÃO SOCIAL";
        dgvDados.Columns[3].Name = "OPERADORA";
        dgvDados.Columns[4].Name = "LINHAS";
        dgvDados.Columns[5].Name = "VIGENCIA";
        dgvDados.Columns[6].Name = "CONTRATO";
        dgvDados.Columns[7].Name = "VALOR GASTO";
        dgvDados.Columns[8].Name = "FIXO EMPRESA";
        dgvDados.Columns[9].Name = "GESTOR";
        dgvDados.Columns[10].Name = "CELULAR";
        dgvDados.Columns[11].Name = "FIXO GESTOR";
        dgvDados.Columns[12].Name = "EMAIL";
        dgvDados.Columns[13].Name = "OBSERVAÇÕES";

        lblRegistros.Text = (dgvDados.Rows.Count - 1).ToString();  
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Olha, sei que não estou respondendo sua dúvida. Mas quero indicar um outro caminho para sua situação com a grid: procure pelo Syncfusion Community. É um conjunto de componentes free (dê uma olhada na FAQ para ver se seu caso se aplica) e ele tem um grid cheia de recursos, entre eles uma linha automática de filtro: a primeira linha da grid não é um dado, é um filtro. Olha o link: https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/sfdatagrid/filterrow